# SIGABRT when tapping button

Tags: ios, rest, button, swift, sigabrt

I have a simple app right now and I have a button called "Load", and I have the following lines.  Every time I run it, I tap the load button to load the details, and when I do, it seems to freeze and cause SIGABRT in thread 1, then brings up the AppDelegate file.  How can I prevent this?  What's wrong?

Edit:  I have narrowed it down to the method itself, for when I made it so it uses the method without the button in ViewDidLoad it causes the exception before I hit anything. Still, why?

```
loadButton.target = self
loadButton.action = "getMovieDetails:353"
```

And the function getMovieDetails

```
// REST Request to get movie details
func getMovieDetails(movieID: Int) {
    let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://yts.re/api/movie.json?id=\(movieID)")
    var request: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest()
    request.URL = url
    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"

    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue(), completionHandler:{ (response:NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        var error: AutoreleasingUnsafePointer<NSError?> = nil
        let json: NSDictionary! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: error) as? NSDictionary

        if json {
            let movieTitleClean: AnyObject! = json["MovieTitleClean"]
            self.navigationItem.title = "\(movieTitleClean)"
        } else {
            self.navigationItem.title = "Error title"
        }


        })
}
```

And the only changed made to appDelegate were in the first method

```
application.setStatusBarHidden(false, animated: false)
application.setStatusBarStyle(UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent, animated: false)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're selector is invalid for the loadButton.action. You cannot give arguments at the end, as you did with `353`. When the button is touched, the parameter will be the button itself, so you should have a function with the following signature:

```
func handleLoadButtonTouch(loadButton: UIButton) { ... }
```

Then, set the action as follows:

```
loadButton.action = "handleLoadButtonTouch:" // note, the ':' is a weird artifact from Obj-C, which simply means 1 argument lives there
```

Comment: So something like `@IBAction func handleLoadButtonTouch(AnyObject) {getMovieDetails(353)}` would work?  Cause when I tried that I still get an error, since, as stated above, the error is in the getMovieDetails method I believe.